# Logo for social martial arts project

Tags: logo, critique, branding

everybody.

I need tips on a new logo I'm making for a social martial arts project.

[image]

[image]

I'm not a designer, so could you give me tips on how I can make it look better? I'm going for a flat design. I'm not sure the kicking kid fits well, as this is a social project for kids on slums. Thanks in advance!

edit: Thank you, guys, for all the feedback. :) My main concern here is that maybe the colors will not always work good depending on the background the logo will be on, so maybe I should have a background on it? I wanted to make it white, but then it'd disappear on a white background. Also, shouldn't I try to put more colors on it? On a side note, I think the logo is too big to the side, but that can't be helped, I guess.

Comment: Looks good and flat to me

Comment: I agree, I think this is pretty good. I think the kid fits with your italic text nicely. I usually don't like italics in logos, but the movement the kid provides at the beginning of the logo makes it work for me. Nice job, non-designer. ;)

Comment: It's an awesome logo, good job. I have some practicality concerns though. The blue and white looks lovely, but I'm concerned that it will struggle to stand out when surrounded by stronger colours. Introducing another colour, even on a small embellishment, may help to draw more attention. The black version simply looks like it's missing a background colour, and the soft blue and hard black clash badly so I would suggest avoiding black backgrounds or giving it a bounding box in white (or of your choosing).

Comment: On a different note, can you try to break down 'make it look better' into focused questions that address any concerns you're having. We have some critique guidelines on the meta to ensure we get well-formulated questions that we can help properly with.

Comment: If your really concerned of the kid make him more angular as that would fit with the texts style. But i dont feel this is a problem. Your logo is a bit wide though and that can cause some problems down the line. Not much you can do about that but you should consider designing a variation with a less wide aspect ratio for business cards etc.

Answer (score 1):

The design looks really good. The only thing I would be concerned about is the length. Consider making a stacked version. I'm currently working on a site where I had to recreate the logo to make it fit and align next to the main navigation.